# Array with js or can i do it in other way

Tags: javascript

i have this data will compare it.

For example: compare only price from the sellers 1 + 2 and show the minimum price with

price(DatasetX)(Number)
Seller(DatasetX)(Number)

How can i do it with js?

Dataset: 1
   Number: 1
   Seller: Seller1
   price: 10.00

Number: 2
   Seller: Seller2
   Price: 20.00

Number: 3
   Seller: Seller3
   price: 9.00

Dataset: 2
   Number: 1
   Seller: Seller4
   price: 6.00

Number: 2
   Seller: Seller2
   Price: 15.00

Number: 3
   Seller: Seller6
   price: 12.00

Number: 4
   Seller: Seller8
   price: 19.00

Dataset: 3
   Number: 1
   Seller: Seller6
   price: 12.00

Number: 2
   Seller: Seller3
   Price: 15.00

Number: 3
   Seller: Seller1
   price: 12.00

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Could you also show some code, in the code format given by SO.

Comment: This looks more like a database (SQL?) task than a JavaScript one. Specially since those datasets have to come from somewhere. Just calculate it on the source if possible and output the result.

Comment: Or at least show us what you get as an input in JS and then the expected output, maybe an example will clarify what you want to do?

Comment: What format is your dataset coming as?

Comment: Do I get this right: You want to compare two entries of an array. The array is structured like that: `{ name: string; price: number}[]`? Or are you using an object like: `{ seller1: 100, seller2: 200 }`